# Can Vlookup return a formula in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, average

I am trying to use the `VLOOKUP` function in excel to return a formula. I've found plenty here on SO about using `VLOOKUP` but have a slightly different question.

I am trying to get the week's average temperature (from column B) before a specified day (in column C) that can be found in column A.

Put more simply:

If date in **cell** C2 exists in **column** A, return **average from range in column** B.

So far this is the closest I've got (thanks to other QAs on SO):

```
=VLOOKUP(C2, A1:B660, AVERAGE(B124:B130), FALSE)
```

However using the `AVERAGE` function in place of column number (which would usually be the argument used) does not seem to work.

I've attached a very simplified picture of my data:

[image: Data]

If `VLOOKUP` is the wrong function to handle this what would be a better approach?
I'm running Excel 15.32 on a Mac.

**EDIT:**

**Dummy data:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/rblk943k2zf71tw/dummy%20data.xlsx?dl=0**

Comment: add maybe a "small" data sample and expected result

Comment: Thanks! I've attached a dummy dataset including formulas recommended in the answers below.

Comment: What is the Range B124:B130 based on? Should it change for each row? You are not communicating some key information if none of these solutions are working.

Comment: The range B124:B130 is the week leading up to the specified date in C. I suspect there was an issue in the linked data (or possibly when I copied over the dummy data into a new sheet). So this has been updated - Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about:

```
=AVERAGE(OFFSET($B:$B,MATCH($C2,$A:$A,0)-1,0,-7))
```

This assumes a header in row 1.

- Find the matched date in column A from the entry in C2
- Create an array of column B values, counting back a week from that point
- Average that array.

You can fill this down column D, for example, and it will adjust as necessary.

One problem  with the `OFFSET` function is that it is volatile, so all the formulas would recalculate if anything is changed on the worksheet.

The following, at least in later versions of Excel, should be non-volatile:

```
=AVERAGE((INDEX($A:$B,MATCH($C2,$A:$A)-6,2,1):INDEX($A:$B,MATCH($C2,$A:$A,0),2)))
```

I will leave it to you to handle the errors from checking dates in rows 2-6.

Comment: Nice approach Ron!

Comment: Thanks Ron, The second line you suggest works well (the first one returned incorrect values and I haven't figured out where the problem was yet).

Comment: @QuinnAsena I edited the first to correct the problem.  The issue was the compensation for the found row not having a weeks worth of data was incorrect.  But I would still recommend the second since it is a non-volatile formula.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be working! Saves me a lot of time doing it manually :)

Answer (score 2):

Use INDEX as a cell reference with MATCH locating the primary date and using that position as well as that position minus 6 for the range.

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(B:B, MATCH(C2, A:A, 0)-6):INDEX(B:B, MATCH(C2, A:A, 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: I'm getting slightly different values for each average for some reason. Couldn't reverse engineer the ranges he was looking for because of this. Now I'm just confused about that more than the original question.

Comment: Ah, I the values are shown rounded. I copied the data instead of downloading the sample file.

Comment: Yes, the ranges your formula averages shifts. They need to be accurately located for each new ending date.

Comment: More impressive than your acumen in Excel, is your ability to read between the lines and interpret the intent of the question. Bravo.

Comment: Thanks for this one, it works well. I have updated the linked file as I suspect there was an issue with it. Should be fine now Jacob - the Index solution works nicely.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is this:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A1:A660,C2)=0,0,AVERAGE(B124:B130))
```

This says if C2 cannot be found in A1:B660, then return 0, otherwise return the AVERAGE(B124:B130).

Comment: Thanks, this works and returns the correct number for the first date but unfortunately when copied down the average range does not copy with the associated rows. AVERAGE(B124:130) becomes AVERAGE(B125:131).

I added your formula to the dummy data linked in the question as an example.

Comment: Adding a '$' in front if a cell reference component will bake it absolute, if that is what you desire. So changing the range to B$124:B$130 will prevent it from changing as you copy up or down. Changing to $B$124:$B$130 will prevent it from changing copying left or right as well. That being said, I'm not following what different value you need for each row? Something in the formula must change from row to row to return a different value.

Comment: Yes it's always a bit tricky to explain excel problems in comments! So the formula gives me the average temperature for the week of the first specified date which is great but when it comes to the second date it still gives me the average temperature of the first specified date (shifted by one row without the '$') rather than the week of the second specified date. Hope that is clearer?

Comment: So you need the average of the week that starts on the date in C? is that the date in C plus 7 days? The range you gave us for the AVERAGE function is averaging the values for dates 7/14/2012-7/20/2012 so that doesn't seem to follow any logic I can build a formula around as far a a specific week.

Comment: I am looking for the average temperature of the week leading up to the date in C, so for the first date (19/07/2012) I am trying to get the average temperature for days 13/07/2012 - 19/07/2012. Likewise for the second date in C. Ron  and Jeeped have suggested using INDEX which seems to have worked!

Comment: Possibly there was an error in sending the spreadsheet link as the date range you mentioned is not the same as what I have highlighted. You're right that wouldn't be logical! Thanks for looking though

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a different approach. Still using `VLOOKUP`, I would go with the below. However there will be an easier/more elegant way to get this done.

- Use `VLOOKUP` to return a value if found. Really, you don't care about the value it returns.

  `=VLOOKUP(C2,A:B,2,FALSE)`
- Wrap in an `IFNA` to handle dates not found. Here I've got it to return -1.

  `=IFNA(VLOOKUP(C2,A:B,2,FALSE),-1)`
- Use an IF statement to work out an average if `VLOOKUP` returns something, and do something else if it's not found.
  `=IF(IFNA(VLOOKUP(C2,A:B,2,FALSE),-1)<>-1,AVERAGE(B124:B130),"do something else")`

Comment: Thanks for this, it works for the first row but does not copy down as the average only shifts one row rather than taking the average of the associated row from which the date was obtained.

I tried it in the dummy data and linked it in the dummy data now attached to the question.